# Limit the depth of hierarchical query

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data, oracle11gr2

I am having a hierarchical table like below. I want to set the `FLAG` attribute based on the `CODE` values. The possible Code values are `R`, `NR`, `RN` and `NF`. The `FLAG` will be set to `'Y'` iff the corresponding code value is consistent with that of parent i.e

```
if parent.code = 'R' and child.code = 'R' then flag = 'Y'
if parent.code = 'NR' and child.code = 'NR' then flag = 'Y'
if parent.code = 'RNR' and child.code = 'R' or 'NR', then flag = 'Y'.
```

Here's my table:

```
create table My_BOM(assign_Id varchar2(50) not null primary key, 
parent_assign_Id varchar2(50) references My_BOM(assign_Id), 
code varchar2(50) not null, 
flag varchar2(1) default 'Y');


insert into my_bom values ('T1',null,'RNR','Y');
insert into my_bom values ('T2','T1','R','Y');
insert into my_bom values ('T3','T2','NR','Y');
insert into my_bom values ('T4','T3','R','Y');
insert into my_bom values ('T5','T1','NF','Y');
insert into my_bom values ('T6','T5','R','Y');
insert into my_bom values ('T7','T1','NR','Y');
insert into my_bom values ('T8','T7','RNR','Y');
insert into my_bom values ('T9','T8','R','Y');
insert into my_bom values ('T10','T1','RNR','Y');
```

How to set the FLAG? This is how I tried but this query also returns the T9 record which I don't want because the chain is broken in between i.e their is inconsistency in the top levels of the `CODE`. so, T9 should n't come as part of the result.

```
select connect_by_root(assign_Id), assign_Id desc_assign_Id, code, flag
from my_bom
where
--exists (select null from my_bom mb where mb.parent_assign_Id = prior my_bom.assign_Id 
--connect by mb.parent_assign_Id = prior mb.assign_Id) and 
DECODE( CODE,
  'R', 'R', 'NR', 'NR', 'RNR',
  :bind_var, NULL) = PRIOR DECODE( CODE,
  'R', 'R', 'NR', 'NR', 'RNR',
  :bind_var, NULL)
  start with parent_assign_Id is null
connect by parent_assign_Id = prior assign_Id
order by desc_assign_Id;
```

`"bind_var"` will be either `'R'` or  `'NR'`

Here's the SQL Fiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/009ad/2/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but you can move the condition to the `connect by` clause to filter out inconsistencies along the entire hierarchy (versus for the last parent/child couple)

```
select connect_by_root(assign_Id), assign_Id desc_assign_Id, code, flag
from my_bom
connect by parent_assign_Id = prior assign_Id
and DECODE( CODE,
  'R', 'R', 'NR', 'NR', 'RNR',
  :bind_var, NULL) = PRIOR DECODE( CODE,
  'R', 'R', 'NR', 'NR', 'RNR',
  :bind_var, NULL)
start with parent_assign_Id is null
order by desc_assign_Id;
```

You may also add `where parent_assign_Id is not null` if you don't want the root :

```
select connect_by_root(assign_Id), assign_Id desc_assign_Id, code, flag
from my_bom
where parent_assign_Id is not null    
connect by parent_assign_Id = prior assign_Id
and DECODE( CODE,
  'R', 'R', 'NR', 'NR', 'RNR',
  :bind_var, NULL) = PRIOR DECODE( CODE,
  'R', 'R', 'NR', 'NR', 'RNR',
  :bind_var, NULL)
start with parent_assign_Id is null
order by desc_assign_Id;
```

Compound `connect by` condition should work with Oracle 10g, I only tested with 11g